# Basic WhatsApp database design in Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, whatsapp, nosql

Just to start a thread to discuss WhatsApp database design in NoSQL. I have designed  database for basic functionality (chat listing,friends listing,chat) in Cassandra.

```
create table friendship(user_id,friend_id,friend_name,mobile_no,status,primary key((user_id),friend_id))

create table chat_list(user_id,message_time,friend_id,last_message,unread_count,primary key((user_id),(message_time)))

create table chat(user_id,friend_id,message_time,message,primary key((user_id,friend_id),message_time))
```

Please provide comment if it can be designed better.

Answer (score 2):

You can not answere this question in general. In cassandra you have to use a query-first design - based on each required query you can start designing the strongly denormalized tables.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Comment: That is what i have done,We need to query for contact listing for a user,that will be served by first table,Chat listing query will be served by second table and third table will be used for chat with a particulate friend.

Comment: O.K. for this 3 queries i would implement it the same way. You can also set a desc ordering for the timestamps...